# ¿cómo ejecutar jQuery desde php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

desde php guardo unos datos en mi base de datos, luego de guardarlos quiero enviar algunos de esos datos que guardo a traves de un webservice que se ejecuta con jquery y ajax pero no se como hacerlo...este es mi php:

```
$sqltk = "INSERT INTO tabla(campo1, campo2, ...)
            VALUES (
                '".$_POST["campo1"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo2"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo3"]."',
                ...
            );";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sqltk) === TRUE) {

   //aqui quiero enviar algunos datos a traves de un webservice

}
```

y este es mi funcion en donde me conecto al servicio para enviar los datos:

```
function notifyService(valor1, valor 2, valor3, ...) {

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "valor1": valor1,
        "valor2": valor2,
        "valor3": valor3,
        ...
    });

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://urldelservicio",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "cache-control": "no-cache",
          "postman-token": "abc123456"
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": data
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    }
```

Mi fuerte no es php, talvez existe otra forma de hacer esto...si es asi, cual seria esa otra forma?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript se ejecuta en el **Cliente** y PHP en el **Servidor**.

El cliente siempre es el que inicia la conexión.

El código del servidor sería:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$sqltk = "INSERT INTO tabla(campo1, campo2, ...)
            VALUES (
                '".$_POST["campo1"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo2"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo3"]."',
                ...
            );";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sqltk) === TRUE) {

   // $data es un array con los datos que 
   // quieres enviar al cliente
   echo json_encode($data);

}
```

y el codigo javascript en el cliente

```
function notifyService(valor1, valor 2, valor3, ...) {

    $.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "https://urldelservicio",
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "content-type": "application/json",
              "cache-control": "no-cache",
              "postman-token": "abc123456"
            },
            processData: false,
            data: {
                campo1: valor1,
                campo2: valor2,
                campo3: valor3
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){
                // json ya es un objeto de javascript listo para usarse
                // Maneja la respuesta aqui.
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa **[echo](http://php.net/manual/es/function.echo.php)** para que js pueda visualizar las variales que te interesan de php.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
$sqltk = "INSERT INTO tabla(campo1, campo2, ...)
            VALUES (
                '".$_POST["campo1"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo2"]."',
                '".$_POST["campo3"]."',
                ...
            );";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sqltk) === TRUE) {

   //aqui quiero enviar algunos datos a traves de un webservice
   echo "<script>";
   echo "notifyService(valor1, valor2, valor3, ...);";
   echo "</script>";
}

function notifyService(valor1, valor2, valor3, ...) {

    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "valor1": <?php echo $_POST["campo1"] ?>,
        "valor2": <?php echo $_POST["campo2"] ?>,
        "valor3": <?php echo $_POST["campo3"] ?>,
        ...
    });

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://urldelservicio",
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json",
          "cache-control": "no-cache",
          "postman-token": "abc123456"
        },
        "processData": false,
        "data": data
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
    }
```

Comment: ok, pero como hago para llamar esa funcion desde mi php? ahi donde deje el espacio comentado es donde quiero ejecutar esa funcion.

Comment: mi pregunta es si puedo llamar esa funcion desde mi php...o hay alguna otra forma de hacer eso que quiero...enviar esos datos que obtengo desde mi php hacia el webservice

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, debes hacer echo's en el php con la función js que quieras ejecutar

Answer (score 0):

Veo que generaste un JSON asi que vas a enviar por POST parametros formateados. Es un web service REST seguramente.

Lo que debes hacer es utilizar CURL, te recomiendo utilizar guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

y te dejo aquí un ejemplo de como lo harías:

Una vez que exportes guzzle a tu proyecto, harias lo siguiente:

```
public function prueba(){
        require _DIR_.'/tuRuta/vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
                'defaults' => ['verify' => true],
                'cookies' => true,
                'base_uri' => 'www.webservice.com/servicio/'
            ]);
        $response = $client->request('POST','Entidad',['json' =>
            [
                'Tu' => 'x',
                'formato' => 'y.', 
                'json' => 'z'
            ]
        ]);

        echo $response->getHeader(); //Te regresa cabecera de la respuesta
        echo $response->getBody(); //Te regresa cuerpo de respuesta.
    }
```

Así todo lo haces desde tu controlador y no expones tu web service. Saludos, espero haber sido de ayuda!